# Redirect requests to matching route with forward slash

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

The [documentation hints at a](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjmk8/index.html#6nisfjmkh) feature that redirects requests for routes without a trailing slash to the matching controller with an otherwise matching Path. And this seems to work, so

```
GET /something
```

is correctly routed to the endpoint

```
@Path("/something/")
public Response doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

Normally this would be fine, it's the behaviour I'd expect, but there are some situations where I'd like to treat the two differently.

For example, I have an endpoint that serves dynamic html which contains relative paths for it's static resources. When the request doesn't has a trailing slash the resources 404.

I get that I can just switch to absolute paths in the html, but I'd like to understand if there's a way to control the Jax routes to do this.

I'd like to do this:

```
@Path("/something")
public Response doSomething() {
    ...
}


@Path("/something/")
public Response doSomethingSlightlyDifferent() {
    ...
}
```

but that gives me a `ModelValidationException` saying the 2 routes are equivalent which correctly isn't allowed.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but you can use regex to make the slash optional `@Path("something{slash: (/)?}")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the slash is optional, that seems to be the default (and usually desired) behaviour, but I want to treat the 2 paths separately. I'll add some clarification to the question.

Comment: You can differentiate same paths with content-negotiation, i.e. different `@Produces`

Comment: Sure, but in this case the response type from both would be same, I just need the route without the trailing slash to be treat as a unique path instead colliding with the path without the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the idea that jersey allows separate handling of Paths ending with "/" vs. those which don't end with it?

[From the docs:](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2001)

> Likewise, by default, a @Path value may or may not end in a '/', it makes no difference, and thus request URLs that end or do not end in a '/' will both be matched.

Comment: I'm getting the idea from the "by default" part of the docs you linked. I'm looking for the other, non-default, options that would hopefully support my use-case.